# Moving out before brackets with XOR

Tags: c++, boolean-logic, multiplication, logical-operators, boolean-operations

If I had the sum of products like `z*a + z*b + z*c + ... + z*y`, it would be possible to move the `z` factor, which is the same, out before brackets: `z(a + b + c + ... y)`.

I'd like to know how it is possible (if it is) to do the same trick if [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) is used instead of multiplication.
`z^a + z^b + ... z^y -> z^(a + b + ... + y)`

Perhaps `a, b, c ...` should be preprocessed, such as logically negated or something else, before adding? `z` could change, so preprocessing, if it's needed, shouldn't depend on particular `z` value.

Comment: AFAIK XOR is not distributive over addition modulo 2^32, so no you can't do that.

Comment: Preprocessing a through y by XORing them with z isn't going to be slower than just negating a through y. It's a trivial operation for a CPU.

Comment: Sounds like a nice math proof exercise: "Prove that there is no function `f_z(x)` such that `Σ(z ^ x_i) = z ^ Σ f_z(x_i)` for all x_i."

Comment: @Alex, It's not for better performance, it's needed to solve a problem.

Comment: Edgeluxe, Although this is an interesting question in its own right, I suggest you post a new question where you describe the problem you're trying to solve, instead of just posting this one where you ask whether one particular solution you've thought of is valid. You might get other, better solutions to your real problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Properties):

> [Distributivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property): with no binary function, not even with itself

So, no, unfortunately, you can't do anything like that with XOR.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that a general formula does not hold you only need to prove a contradiction in a limited case.
We can reduce it to show that this does not hold:
`(a^b) * c = (a^c) * (b^c)`

It is trivial to show that one base case fails as such:

```
a = 3
b = 1
c = 1

(a^b) * c = (3^1) * 1 = 2
(a^c) * (b^c) = 2 * 0 = 0
```

Using the same case you can show that `(a*b) ^ c = (a^c) * (b^c)` and `(a + b) ^ c = (a^c) + (b^c)` do not hold either.
Hence, equality does not hold in a general case.
Equality can hold in special cases though, which is an entirely different subject.

Comment: Thank you. I was specifically looking for xor distributing over multiplication.